# objective-C/Swift: add child view/controller into superview, but with controller included

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swift

Till now I have worked in different RAD IDE's such as C# and Delphi, and xCode/ObjectiveC/Swift concepts are still new to me (also all is mixed in my head right now :))

Here is my application:

- Storyboard with 2 view controllers, both are having classes associated.
- Views/Controllers are not connected in any way via Interface Builder
- One view controller will be started at app start.
- Let the starting view is empty, and on second there is a 1 UIButton
- I have made IBOutlet and IBAction for this button in my controller and it does some change, e.g change color or something else.

I want to place one view into another (child into super view), but I also want to keep that controller of child view is still in control of its own view.

So, when child view is added into new view/controller - I still can click on button from child controller and do the action written in controller code.

I know how to add bare view into another view (via addView method), but I am losing controller.

I am not sure if is this possible at all, maybe I am missing a whole concept of MVC coding, but maybe is trivial.

I hope that I have explained well.

Edit:

This is what I get for solution:

```
let ingredientsController = IngredientsController(nibName: "IngredientsController", bundle: nil)
addChildViewController(ingredientsController)
ingredientsController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 200)
scrollView.addSubview(ingredientsController.view)
```

Comment: You're looking for [container view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: Thank you, now I am reading this document. Will try to google for some tutorials too.

Comment: Sounds good. I'd help you more, but I've never used them myself.

Comment: It seems to my test work, this is what I have done:    let ingredientsController = IngredientsController(nibName: "IngredientsController", bundle: nil)
        
addChildViewController(ingredientsController)

ingredientsController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 200)

view.addSubview(ingredientsController.view)

Comment: ps. sorry for bad formatting, I am still new to stackoverflow posting :(

Comment: That's good that it works. If it works, feel free to answer your own question. Four spaces denotes code. I think you can also use code tags.